# How to sanitize and validate user input to pass a Checkmarx scan in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkmarx, secure-coding

**In Checkmarx scan I am receiving the vulnerable EXCEPTION,**

gets user input for the **dr element**. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method

```
 List<survey_bene> surveybenelist = new List<survey_bene>();
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ResondantCode FROM Respondant");
 DataTable dtdetails = vdm.SelectQuery(cmd).Tables[0];
 if (dtdetails.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     foreach (DataRow dr in dtdetails.Rows)
      {
         survey_bene survey = new survey_bene();
         survey.resondantcode = dr["ResondantCode"].ToString();
         surveybenelist.Add(survey);
      }
 }
```

Comment: What's line in code is reported not safe? This code for collecting data from UI or sending data to the UI?

Comment: survey.resondantcode = dr["ResondantCode"].ToString(); in this line, we are sending data to the UI

Comment: @user3755418 what is the exact vulnerability that Checkmarx tells you?

Comment: Hi roman canlas,   gets user input for the dr element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to the user in method

Answer (score 0):

My question in the comments weren't exactly answered, but I'm assuming it is an XSS vulnerability. If it isn't then I will update my answer accordingly.

Based on this assumption, you should call the [HtmlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpServerUtility_HtmlEncode_System_String_) functions from either the [HtmlServerUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode?view=netframework-4.8) or [HttpUtility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmlencode?view=net-5.0) classes:

```
 List<survey_bene> surveybenelist = new List<survey_bene>();
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ResondantCode FROM Respondant");
 DataTable dtdetails = vdm.SelectQuery(cmd).Tables[0];
 if (dtdetails.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     foreach (DataRow dr in dtdetails.Rows)
      {
         survey_bene survey = new survey_bene();
         survey.resondantcode = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dr["ResondantCode"].ToString());
         surveybenelist.Add(survey);
      }
 }
```